# stream_get_contents is not working

Tags: php

I am trying to send a POST request to a website to login and them get the contents and parse them. But when I echo the result nothing is there. Any help?

```
<?php

   $data = array('loginuser' => 'user', 'loginpassword' => 'pass', 'loginschool' => 'krr');

   // use key 'http' even if you send the request to https://...
   $options = array(
      'http' => array(
          'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
          'method'  => 'POST',
          'content' => http_build_query($data),
       ),
    );
   $context  = stream_context_create($options);
   $result = stream_get_contents($url);
   echo $result;


   $dom = new DOMDocument();
   $dom->loadHTML('https://intranet.tam.ch/krr/external/index/act/tt_oneclassNew');

   $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
   $iframe = $xpath->query('//body//iframe');
   foreach ($iframe as $frame) {
      var_dump(trim($frame->nodeName));
      echo 'lol';
   }
   echo 'lulz';
?>
```

Btw. I do the same on iOS and it works. allow_url_open is on. I also tried a way via curl. Doesn't work eithter.

Comment: You are not reading from the stream you create.

Comment: Agree with Elliot - $url isn't defined in that piece of code.

Comment: '$url' is defined sorry, Didn't include it.

Answer (score 0):

Like others have mentioned.. the `$url` is missing from the example. And besides that you are not using the stream you created.

```
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$fp = fopen($url, 'rb', false, $context);
$result = stream_get_contents($fp);

echo $result;
```

of use `file_get_contents`

```
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

echo $result;
```

Comment: This does work, but it only displays the login screen of the Website, not the one when you are logged in.

Comment: Looks fine. Try removing the `\r\n` in your header